# add method to Eloquent relation

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I've defined a relation like this

```
class Contact extends Model
{
    public function phones()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Phones::class, "contact_id");
    }   
}
```

Then, in `ContactsController`, I can access a contact's phones

```
$contact->phones()
```

which returns `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany`. Now, I would like to do something with that relation (or any relation like that), let's say I want to perform some validation. I would like to do something like this:

```
$contact->phones()->doSomething();
```

And in `doSomething()` have access to the parent (contact) and the relation (phones). I tried adding a trait to the model, but I'm getting an error

> Call to undefined method
> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany::doSomething()

So, is it possible to achieve what I want? I know I can create a method and pass `$contact->phones()` as an argument and work with that, but I'm curious if my approach is doable

Comment: `doSomething()` needs to be a method available to the `Builder` Class (`HasMany` being an extension of that), which is why stuff like `$contact->phones()->where('country_code', '+1')` would work. Or, if you call `$contact->phones` (without the `()`), it would need to be a Collection method, like `$contact->phones->filter(function ($phone) { return $phone->country_code == '+1'); });`, etc. So yes, it's possible to do what you're suggesting, but you'd have to find a way to make whatever method you're defining available on the Class, which I'm not sure how you'd do.

Comment: @TimLewis scopes have access to the builder

Comment: @medilies Well yes, `public function scopeSomething()`, then calling `$phone->something()` would be a Builder instance, but this question doesn't (currently) have anything to do with Scopes. Are you trying to suggest that they should define `public function scopeDoSomething()` and use that? Because yes, that _should_ work, depending on what the Scope is doing. That part is not clear from the question.

Comment: You can add custom methods via macros.

Comment: @TimLewis I will read about scopes, in the meantime...would that be usefull in a generic way? I mean, not narrowed to a specific model o hasMany relation. Today is `$contact->phones` but tomorow maybe I'll need it to `$contact->emails()`

Comment: @Harven can you point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As `HasMany` relationship class has `Macroable` trait, You can extend it to add custom method.

Add in `AppServiceProvider` boot method:

```php
HasMany::macro('yourCustomMethod', function($yourParameters) {
    // Laravel binds $this to context of macro, not the class where you defined it.
    return $this;
});
```

You will be able to do this:

```php
$contact->phones()->yourCustomMethod();
```

Comment: Do you know how to get the string `phones` inside `yourCustomMethod()`?

Comment: @MatíasCánepa I don't get what you mean. If you want to know on what model relation was called, you can check it using $parent property ($this->parent inside your anonymous function).